# Decompilation android flash apk

Tags: android, apk, flash

Can I decompile android application written on flash (not on java)

When I decompile such apk I receive java files. But there should be swf files.

Is there any way?

Help please.

Answer (score 0):

The apk finally contains the dex code after compiling and packaging the app in android.
Since there is DVM(Now ART) which runs the dex code, so the code written in other languages get converted to the dex code on the compilation and export on the build

You are using an decompiler which is decompiling the dex code in to the java files.

Comment: So, I should use other decompiler (for flash)?
Or I cant decompile non-native apk?
Or I should decompile in java and then convert to flash?